# How to settup android studio in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04

I downloaded android studio for ubuntu 12.04. but i don't know how to put JAVA_HOME and how to open studio for developing apps. please help me.

Comment: Start with this: `export JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java>`

Comment: Using export will only define JAVA_HOME for the current session. To make it permanent, add the command in your .bahsrc file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open your Android Studio by navigating to main-directory/bin through Terminal and then on the next line open studio.sh using the command `./studio.sh` . For example if you installed Android Studio in Downloads, you have to write in Terminal `cd Downloads/android-studio/bin` and after confirming the second line should be `./studio.sh`. I think in Android 0.8(beta) they still didn't fix that issue where you can't open your Studio through the icon.

Comment: I am getting this error. ''tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.'

Comment: yes, there is a bug, now it is working when i go through Terminal.